# Extract TD from TBODY

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I extract  Commission I, Legislation Committee, Ad-Hoc Committee from tr?

```
<tr>
<td class="text-center">1</td>
<td class="hidden-xs"><a href="/en/anggota/detail/id/1319"><img class="img-responsive" src="/doksigota/photo/1319.jpg"/></a></td>
<td><a href="/en/anggota/detail/id/1319">PROF. DR. BACHTIAR ALY, MA</a><br/>National Democrat Party Faction<br/>ACEH I</td>
<td>Commission I<br/>Legislation Committee<br/>Ad-Hoc Committee</td> </tr
```

```
webpage_response = requests.get('http://www.dpr.go.id/en/anggota')
webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
tbody = soup.find("tbody")
for i in tbody:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `all_td = soup.find("tbody").find_all("td")`, `print(i.get_text())`

Comment: it is good to read all [documentation for BS](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to learn all its functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete solution.

## Solution

#### Step-1

Get table body.

```py
# Show exported info as a table
import pandas as pd 
# Progressbar
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_notebook, tnrange 
# Read HTML Page
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Access Web URL
import requests

base_url = 'http://www.dpr.go.id/en/anggota'
webpage_response = requests.get(base_url)
webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
tbody = soup.find("tbody")
```

#### Step-2

Iterate over the table row elements: `<tr>...</tr>`. For each table row, extract the columns and save them into a `dict`: `rows_dict`.

```py
rows_dict = dict()
trs = tbody.find_all('tr')
for tr in tqdm_notebook(trs, desc='Progress'):    
    row_dict = extract_columns(tr)
    rows_dict.update({row_dict['ID']: row_dict})
```

#### Step-3

Show the extracted data in **tabular** form using **pandas dataframe**. Note that you are interested in columns: `['COL_2', 'COL_3', 'COL_4']`. However, if you need to access any other data from the same `html` table, now you have that as well in the dataframe `df`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(rows_dict).T
headers = ['ID', 'CANDIDATE', 'AFFILIATION', 'COL_1', 'COL_2', 'COL_3', 'COL_4', 'IMAGE_URL', 'URL']
df = df[headers]
df.head()
```

### Necessary Custom Functions:

```py
def extract_columns(tr, debug_flag = False):    
    # headers = ['ID', 'CANDIDATE', 'AFFILIATION', 'COL_1', 'COL_2', 'COL_3', 'COL_4', 'IMAGE_URL', 'URL']
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    urls = tds[1].find('a', href=True)
    person = tds[2].find('a', href=True)
    party = drop_html_br_tags(tds[2].contents.copy())
    party_len = len(party)
    committees = drop_html_br_tags(tds[3].contents.copy())
    committees_len = len(committees)
    if debug_flag: 
        print(party)
        print(committees)
    row_dict = {'ID': tds[0].text, 
                'URL': base_url+str(urls['href']), 
                'IMAGE_URL': base_url+str(urls.find('img').get_attribute_list('src')[0]), 
                'CANDIDATE': person.text.strip(),
                'AFFILIATION': party[1].strip() if (party_len>1) else None,
                'COL_1': party[2].strip() if (party_len>2) else None, 
                'COL_2': committees[0].strip() if (committees_len>0) else None,  
                'COL_3': committees[1].strip() if (committees_len>1) else None, 
                'COL_4': committees[2].strip() if (committees_len>2) else None, 
                }

    return row_dict

def drop_html_br_tags(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if str(line) in ['<br/>']:
            #print(f'{i}')
            #print('{}'.format(line))
            lines.remove(line)
    return lines
```

#### Test The Functions:

```py
row_dict = extract_columns(trs[2])
row_dict
```

**Output**

```
{'AFFILIATION': 'National Democrat Party Faction',
 'CANDIDATE': 'PRANANDA SURYA PALOH',
 'COL_1': 'SUMATERA UTARA I',
 'COL_2': 'Commission I',
 'COL_3': 'Committee for Inter-Parliamentary Cooperation',
 'COL_4': None,
 'ID': '3',
 'IMAGE_URL': 'http://www.dpr.go.id/en/anggota/doksigota/photo/1329.jpg',
 'URL': 'http://www.dpr.go.id/en/anggota/en/anggota/detail/id/1329'}
```